# CameraX doesn't open camera or take a photo in Android app

Tags: android, kotlin

I was developing an app, where I try to make a camera app using CameraX plugin of android with kotlin as lenguage.

So I made an activity like this:

cameraActivity.kt

```
class CameraActivity : ListenerCompatActivity(), ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
companion object {
    const val TAKE_PICTURE = 200
}

private val useCase = Application.useCaseManager.camera
private lateinit var ui: ActivityCameraBinding
private var lensFacing : Int = LENS_FACING_BACK
private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
private var flashMode: Int = FLASH_MODE_OFF
private var resultSent = false
override fun getActivityID(): ActivityID = ActivityID.Camera

override fun isKeepScreenOn() = true

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    ui = ActivityCameraBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(ui.root)
    setListeners()

}


private fun setListeners() {
    runOnUiThread {
        ui.btCancelCamera.setOnClickListener {
            //TODO: Check what to do
        }
        // Changes the flash mode when the button is clicked
        ui.btSwitchFlashlight.setOnClickListener {
            val flashMode = imageCapture?.flashMode
            if (flashMode == FLASH_MODE_ON) imageCapture?.flashMode = FLASH_MODE_OFF
            else imageCapture?.flashMode = FLASH_MODE_ON
        }
        ui.viewFinder.setOnClickListener {
            //TODO:
        }

        ui.btTakePhoto.setOnClickListener {
            imageCapture?.takePicture(
                ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
                object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
                    override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
                        val request = useCase.getCameraRequest() //TODO: Check how use request

                        useCase.setResult(ApiCameraResponse(
                            result = ApiCameraResponse.Result(
                                imageContent = image,
                                imageType = "png"
                            )
                        ))
                    }

                    override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                        logger.error("Error taking picture: $exception")
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    // Check and request permissions
    if (hasNoPermissions()) {
        checkCameraPermissions(applicationContext)
    }
}
/*

private fun startCamera() {
    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

    cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
        // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
        val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

        // Preview
        val preview = Preview.Builder()
            .build()
            .also {
                //it.setSurfaceProvider(ui.viewFinder.surfaceTexture)
            }

        // Select back camera as a default
        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

        try {
            // Unbind use cases before rebinding
            cameraProvider.unbindAll()

            // Bind use cases to camera
            cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                this, cameraSelector, preview
            )

        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            logger.error("Use case binding failed: $exc")
        }

    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
}
*/

private fun sendCancelResult() {
    sendResult(
        ApiCameraResponse().also { it.setFailed(Messages.CANCEL_BY_USER) }
    )
}

private fun sendResult(result: ApiCameraResponse) {
    logger.info("Sending result = $result")
    resultSent = true
    useCase.setResult(result)
}
/**
 * Bind the Camera to the lifecycle
 */
private fun bindCamera() {
    val pcp = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(applicationContext).get()
    pcp.unbindAll()
    val height = resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels
    val width = resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels

    var preview = Preview.Builder()
        .setTargetResolution(Size(width,height))
        .build()

    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(applicationContext)
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
        preview = Preview.Builder().build().apply {
            setSurfaceProvider(ui.viewFinder.createSurfaceProvider(null))
        }
        imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
            .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
            .setTargetRotation(windowManager.defaultDisplay.rotation)
            .setFlashMode(flashMode)
            .build()
        //TODO: Pass LensFacing to imageCapture

    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(applicationContext))

    // Bind the camera to the lifecycle
    pcp.bindToLifecycle(this as LifecycleOwner, DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA, preview)
}

/**
 * Check if the app has all permissions
 */
private fun hasNoPermissions(): Boolean {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}

/**
 * Request all permissions
 */
fun checkCameraPermissions(context: Context?) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context!!, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        // Permission is not granted
        Log.d("checkCameraPermissions", "No Camera Permissions")
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA),
            100
        )
    }
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    when (PermissionChecker.isGranted(
        requestCode,
        grantResults
    )) {
        true -> {
            bindCamera()
            logger.info("permission granted")
        }

        else -> {
            logger.info("Permission not been granted")
        }
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
}
```

}

Which show me an iinterface like the follwing base on my xml file:

activity_camara.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:id="@+id/divCameraHW"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/footerLogo"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/view_finder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btTakePhoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Take Photo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CameraPreview
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CameraPreview>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btSwitchFlashlight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:text="@string/turn_on_flashlight"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btCancelCamera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
```

This is my activity when I compile the app in my device:

[image]

No one of the button do nothing ( I mean Take Photo button, and Encender Flash button due to cancel button actually do nothing), and bring me any kind of information which I can work.

So What Am I missing here?

Take thanks in advance !

[EDIT]

Regarding my manifest permission are the follwing:

```
 <!-- NETWORK PERMISSIONS -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <!-- BLUETOOTH SCAN PERMISSIONS -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <!-- GPS -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- MISC PERMISSIONS -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
        android:required="true"
        android:requiredFeature="true"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Comment: Can you make sure that your bindCamera() method is getting invoked?

Comment: debugging the code, I check bindCamera() is been callled, BUT, I realize the variable 'grantsResult' in onRequestPermissionsResult method is "-1". So I guess is a permission issue?

Comment: -1 means that permission is denied. You need to check around your permission requesting code. Also, you can check if the camera permission is granted in your App management settings (Device settings -> App management -> your app -> permissions -> camera permission)

Comment: One more important thing to check, Have you mentioned the camera permission in your manifest file?

Comment: I update my question addding the manifest peremission